# How to track event (click on menu item) in Google Analytics for WordPress 4+?

Tags: wordpress, google-analytics

I wanted to add this code in specific menu custom link item in main navigation of WordPress website:

```
gtag('event', 'Click to Call', { 'event_category': 'Phone Call Tracking', 'event_label': '088545745', 'value': 0 });
```

How to do that?

Comment: You can do this with a custom Javascript function (based, for example, on the menu class) or you can use Google Tag Manager.

Comment: @MichelePisani Thank you for the comment. How to do that exactly with menu class and what Javascript code looks like?

Comment: In this case I suggest a simpler way, that is to access the template in WP where there is the menu and insert the tracking directly to the link with onclick.

Comment: How to target specific item in main menu in this way?

Comment: It depends on the template used in WP and on the element you want to track. You must search for it in the template file. It is not a question that you can solve here with some answers.